# Search a column in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Suppose I have a database **`My_DB`** with hundreds of tables.

Now, I need to find about a particular column **`My_Emp_ID`** in my database.

I tried manually searching each table, but it is not efficient.

What is the best way to find all the tables that contain column **`My_Emp_ID`** ?

You can assume that `schema` is same for all the tables present in the database.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3449/making-sql-server-metadata-queries-easier-with-these-new-views/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'My_Emp_ID'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use AdventureWorks2019

SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.name) AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%Demographics%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Answer (score -1):

From the SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-table-definition?view=sql-server-ver16):

> You could alternatively query the system catalog views directly to query object metadata information about tables, schema, and columns. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name as schema_name, t.name as table_name, c.* FROM sys.columns AS c
> INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
> INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
> WHERE t.name = 'mytable' AND s.name = 'dbo';
> ```

Additionally filter result by column_name.

Comment: Your answer is giving me blank columns. Is that because of using Azure SQL?